# How to make fixed size window in privacy.resistfingerprinting (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, window

In Firefox, I use `privacy.resistfingerprinting = true`. How can I set the window size *(1024x768 or 1366x768 or another)* that I need? So that I open the browser and the window size matches the resolution I need.

What I did:

Set the values to `privacy.window.maxInnerHeight` and `privacy.window.maxInnerWidth`. But the size is 1000x700, 1400x800, etc., i.e. not the one i need.

Used `privacy.resistfingerprinting.letterboxing` with the specified resolution in `.dimensions`, it seems to work. **BUT**, this works with a delay. I open a test page in which resolution is displayed through `<body onload="alert (window.innerWidth)">` and at the very beginning the real value is displayed and only then changed using letterboxing. That is, it is possible to intercept the real value.

I tried to resize the window through `Window.resizeTo ()`, but it does not change.

Tell me how to launch a browser with a window of the desired size with privacy.resistfingerprinting enabled?